# get columns which have same value in all rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

suppose following is my table:-

```
COL1 | COl2 | COL3
-----|----- |-----
1    |  2   | 3
1    |  2   | 3
1    |  4   | 3
```

I want record from each column which has a single value in all row.

For the above sample data, I want:

```
1,NULL,3
```

as the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation and `case`.  For your data:

```
select (case when min(col1) = max(col1) then min(col1) end) as col1,
       (case when min(col2) = max(col2) then min(col2) end) as col2,
       (case when min(col3) = max(col3) then min(col3) end) as col3
from t;
```

I strongly recommend using `min()` and `max()` instead of `count(distinct)`.  The latter tends to have poor performance.

Comment: Just have to beware of how nulls would be treated of course, but that applies to count(distinct ...) also.

Comment: thanks. Could you please explain how this one is better?

Comment: @nit710: if you have an indexes on the columns, min() or max() can be evaluated in pretty much constant time regardless of how many rows the table has. count() has to go through all rows to find out how many there are.

Comment: And even without indexes, this is a single pass through the data.  `count(distinct)` can take longer because it has to find the values and then find the distinct ones among them.

Comment: Thanks! I saw the results myself. This indeed takes much less time.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by doing a count distinct:

```
select 
  case when count(distinct col1) = 1 then min(col1) end as col1,
  case when count(distinct col2) = 1 then min(col2) end as col2,
  case when count(distinct col3) = 1 then min(col3) end as col3
from tbl
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select case when count(distinct col1) = 1 then max(col1) else null end,
       case when count(distinct col2) = 1 then max(col2) else null end,
       case when count(distinct col3) = 1 then max(col3) else null end
from table;
```